# WebBrowser control executing from service issue

Tags: c#, windows-services, .net-2.0, browser, shdocvw

Ok, so here's the deal -- I'm running a Windows Forms `WebBrowser` control from a service.  I know thats a no-no, but it seems to work alright.

The only thing I'm running into a problem with is trying to wait for the browser's pages to load.  In a normal application, I'd just do something like

```
while (browser.readystate != complete)
Application.DoEvents()
```

Obviously this won't work from a service.

I've tried this as an alternative:

```
public class WebCrawler
{
    private class ExposedActiveXWebBrowser : System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
    {
        public SHDocVw.WebBrowser UnderlyingWebBrowser
        {
            get
            {
                return ActiveXInstance as SHDocVw.WebBrowser;
            }
        }
    }
    ExposedActiveXWebBrowser worker;

    public WebBrowserReadyState ReadyState
    {
        get
        {
            return worker.ReadyState;
        }
    }

    public HtmlDocument Document
    {
        get
        {
           return worker.Document;
        }
    }

    public WebCrawler()
    {
        worker = new ExposedActiveXWebBrowser();
    }

    public void Navigate(string urlString)
    {
        worker.Navigate(urlString);
        while (worker.UnderlyingWebBrowser.ReadyState != tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
            Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
}
```

That Navigate method, however, doesn't work.  The ReadyState never changes from LOADING.

What I'm wondering is this -- Windows forms WebBrowsers seem to be inherently asynchronous, so does that mean the ActiveX control is already executing on its own thread?

**Can I, by accessing the underlying activex control through an appropriate interface, just wait for it to complete?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: I needed to run the service as a user with full trust.  it's explicitly required via the PermissionSet attribute.

Comment: The guy above is probably right -- shouldn't really need to use WebBrowser anyway.  It's not going work quite correctly in a service and might be way heavier than you need for whatever you're doing.

i didn't know any better when i did this initially.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event.

From MSDN:

Occurs when the WebBrowser  control finishes loading a document.

...

Handle the DocumentCompleted event to receive notification when the new document finishes loading. When the DocumentCompleted event occurs, the new document is fully loaded, which means you can access its contents through the Document, DocumentText, or DocumentStream  property.

Comment: That event won't fire.  That's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As your class is called WebCrawler, can I assume that this service requests HTML an does something with it?

If that is the case then there are better classes to use to do this and you won't have this issue.

Such as `System.Net.WebClient` and `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`

Comment: Yeah, I've used those.  The problem I've run into is figuring out a lot of the authentication hoops I've got to jump through to get to certain pages.

Comment: @Joshua, what authentication problems are you having? Maybe they'd make for a good followup question.

Comment: Thats a possibility and thats how I'd like to eventually handle this problem, but can anyone answer my question just to satisfy my curiousity?

Does the ActiveX control get its own thread?  Is there a reason the readystate isn't changing?

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Chris -- If you can't see the WebControl why would you want to render it?  Use something like the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse a DOM model for the page if needed.